# Remove specific user from a numbered group that I don't know the number of

Tags: powershell, active-directory

As Title states, I am trying to use Powershell to remove a user from an Active Directory group that has the naming scheme of Group # with group always being the same word but the # being anything 1-20.  Not sure which group the specific user is a part of so I am trying to use a wildcard "*" but it doesn't seem to want to work with

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Group *" -Members "test"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `-Identity` parameter is for when you have a single *distinct* group identity (a distinguished name, SAMAccountName, security identifier, or object GUID of an existing group).

Instead, use `Get-ADGroup` with the `-Filter` parameter to search for the relevant groups, then pipe them to `Remove-ADGroupMember`:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'Group *'" |Remove-ADGroupMember -Members "test"
```